# Sign of the eigenvalues of the product of 3 matrices

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, symmetric-matrices, positive-semidefinite

I'm trying to find the sign of the eigenvalues of a certain $n\times n$ symmetric matrix $M$.
I know that i can write this matrix as
$$M = PDP^T,$$

with $D$ $p\times p $ diagonal with positive or null entries, and $P$ a $n \times p$ matrix.
Can I conclude that the eigenvalues of $M$ are positive or null ?

Comment: The number of eigenvalues of $M$ is not the same as the number of entries of $D$.

Comment: If $M$ is $n \times n$, do we agree that $P$ is $n \times p$ ($n$ rows, $p$ columns) with $p>n$, whereas $D$ is $p \times p$?

Comment: @Jean, if $P$ is $n\times p$, and $D$ is $n\times n$, then $PD$ is not defined.

Comment: Have you tried working through any examples, Djekt?

Comment: @Gerry Myerson You are right. I just corrected my comment...

Comment: Sorry there was a stupid error in my question, i edited my question.

Comment: Can you say whether $n>p$ or $n<p$ ?

Comment: In my case, $n>p$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For all $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$,

$$\langle x, Mx\rangle=\langle x, PDP^T x\rangle=\langle P^T x, DP^T x\rangle=\langle D^{1/2} P^T x, D^{1/2} P^T x\rangle\ge 0.$$

So all eigenvalues of $M$ are nonnegative.

Answer (score 2):

A couple of things that are useful to note. $PP^\top$ is symmetric positive semi-definite.

I think furthermore, denote $\lambda_1,d_1$ the smallest eigenvalue of $PP^\top$ and smallest entry of the main diagonal of $D$ respectively. $\lambda_2,d_2$ for largest. Then I believe $\sigma(PDP^\top)\subset[\lambda_1d_1, \lambda_2d_2]$ by Cauchy's Inequality on matrix products.

I think this gives the answer to your problem.

Comment: Could you please provide a link/reference to "Cauchy's Inequality on matrix products" ?

Comment: Cauchy-Schwartz holds for any norm. Take as norm $||A|| = max eigenvalue of A$ and use ||P^TAP|| = ||A||||P^TP||.

Alternatively, look at @md5 solution, which is much clearer/more concrete.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, I was not sure you were referring to CS. I assume that by its "matrix product" version you mean that the inner product considered is the frobenius inner product on matrices. Anyway, to be honest, I am not sure I see how to use CS to prove the lower bound on the spectrum.